# How can I recreate the shadows and blur effect using Gimp?

Tags: gimp, effects, blur

So I'm fairly new when it comes to working with images and creating different effects.

But can anyone explain what effect is being applied to the conference logos in the following [link](http://espn.go.com/nhl/story/_/id/8850084/2013-nhl-postseason-simulation)?

The middle of the logo is brighter and as you work your way outward, it gets darker.

[image]

Are there any good tutorials to reference in to recreate this effect? I'll be mainly using Gimp for this.

Comment: Can you explain which effect you mean? Beeing unsharp, the bottom of the logo is more in front than the top of the logo, ...

Comment: The middle of the logo is brighter...if you go outward towards the edges it gets darker...sorry for the non-technical terms though.

Comment: No problem, I just want to make your question clearer to help you to get a proper answer. I think it would be a good idea to edit your question and include this information ... And welcome to graphicdesign.SE!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like there are two layers on top of the original logo:

1. Light grey to black radial gradient - in Multiply mode, and
2. The original logo duplicated and blurred - in Lighten mode - probably with opacity around 50%

Comment: Seems like this may be the case, now to figure out how to replicate the process in Gimp.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda agree with the answer by Const, but you can also do this by:

1. Adding a vignette to the logo—you can do this by going to `Filters > Lights and Shadows > Vignette`
2. Add a Gaussian Blur, which is also can be found via `Filters > Blur > Gaussian Blur`

Here, you can mess around with the settings until it matches perfectly with your desired images. Hope this answer helps :D